# Remove specific consecutive characters duplications from std::string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, unique, std

Perhaps anyone have an efficient way to remove consecutive duplications of specific characters preferably using built-in string operations, and without explicitly going through the string characters.

For example, when I have wildcard pattern and I'd like to remove consecutive asterisks only (`*`)
`/aaaa/***/bbbb/ccc/aa/*****/dd --> /aaaa/*/bbbb/ccc/aa/*/dd`

For all characters repetitive duplications I can use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in the following manner :

`str.erase( std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end());`

but what about specific chars only.

Comment: you could use regex replace but it'd probably just be better in this case to homebrew something

Comment: Use `std::remove_if` with a mutable lambda, followed by `erase()`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is it guaranteed that elements are visited consecutively?

Comment: According to `cppreference` it is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you link the passage? I didn't find it. Edit : I guess the algorithm accepts forward iterators, so if you pass one of those you're guaranteed consecutive visits. It bothers me that I can't find it explicitly said. If you pass a random access iterator, I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed to perform out-of-order evaluations of the predicate. Specially since the algorithm accepts an `ExecutionPolicy`, meaning it seems to be intended to be multithreaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same algorithm `std::unique` with a lambda expression.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "/aaaa/***/bbbb/ccc/aa/*****/dd"; 
    char c = '*';

    s.erase( std::unique( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), 
                          [=]( const auto &c1, const auto &c2 ) { return c1 == c && c1 == c2; } ),
             std::end( s ) ); 

    std::cout << s << '\n';             
}
```

The program output is

```
/aaaa/*/bbbb/ccc/aa/*/dd
```

Or you can remove a set of duplicate characters. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "/aaaa/***/bbbb/ccc/aa/*****/dd"; 
    const char *targets = "*b";

    auto remove_chars = [=]( const auto &c1, const auto &c2 )
    {
        return strchr( targets, c1 ) && c1 == c2;
    };
    s.erase( std::unique( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), remove_chars ), 
             std::end( s ) ); 

    std::cout << s << '\n';             
}
```

The program output is

```
/aaaa/*/b/ccc/aa/*/dd
```

In the last example I suppose that the character `'\0'` is not included in the string. Otherwise you have to add one more subexpression to the logical expression in the lambda.